# How to reduce shutter lag in camera for android?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I am trying to take 20 or more pictures from camera which i will use later. I am able to take pictures but there is shutter lag and i have to wait for the capture event to happen and only after that i can take another pic. Can anyone please help me with this? I want to reduce this lag. Was not able to find anything in Camera.Parameters. Waiting for responses.

Even after putting the capture event in asynctask the lag stays. Any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The camera is only as fast as the hardware. There's no amount of wishing -- or camera parameters -- that are going to make any camera faster than the hardware can go.

Comment: Agreed. I was looking at an app named GifBoom which gives the user ability to click 20 pics at his/her own pace and i am assuming capturing image is done in a asynctask. Is it possible to put the takePicture() in asynctask? This will atleast wont make the user wait for the capture to happen.

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I assume they're almost certainly using the camera in video mode and turning the video into an animated GIF.

Comment: i guess having setPreviewCallBackWithBuffer should do the magic. Will keep you posted if it works